How can I setup PyCharm to run the x86 version of python and/or the proper architecture (X86) through the console?
I am trying to run PyCharm w/ Rosetta on a M1 macbook.
I have a venv that runs a X86 version of python, which I have added to my proejct.
Within PyCharm settings, I have added env /usr/bin/arch -x86_64 /bin/zsh --login to Tools->Terminal->shell path".
When I run python in PyCharm terminal and check the platform with python -c "import platform; print(platform.machine())" it shows as X86_64.
However, when I attempt to run my code through the PyCharm console (e.g., by hitting the run button), the same platform commands output arm64.
How can I setup PyCharm to run the x86 version of python and/or the proper architecture (X86) through the console?
